# Xcode, swift: alert not dismissing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
class AVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.a()
    }

    func a(){
        ZZZ.remove(for: self)
    }
}

class ZZZ {

    func remove(for viewController: UIViewController){
        viewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        //Why won't the alert created in AVC be dismissed from here?
    }
}
```

Hi there,
I have a view controller AVC that creates an alert & a loading indicator.
I wish to dismiss this alert from another swift file called ZZZ using ZZZ's remove function.
However, the alert is not dismissed from ZZZ even though my code clearly asks it to.
How do I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: you are trying to remove AVC as per your code then why would alert be dismissed. Pass the reference of alert controller to remove it

Comment: but i did by passing ```self``` in remove?

Comment: Self in AVC not alert

Comment: call `ZZZ.remove(for: alert)`. - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51820747/4061501)

Comment: where you are creating ZZZ object ?

Comment: try `func a(vc:UIViewController)` and call `a(vc: alert)` and inside a `ZZZ.remove(for: vc)`

Comment: Neel bhaai!! :D We are here too!

Comment: @iPeter answer de fir

Comment: The question is already answered. :D

Answer (score 0):

You are currently dismissing the viewcontroller, not alert. Call

```
alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)


func a() {
        ZZZ().remove(for: alert)
}
```

Comment: @Helosy Try `ZZZ()` instead of `ZZZ`

Answer (score 0):

Here shared is custom class for showing alert

```
class Shared: NSObject {
    func waitAlert() -> UIAlertController {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
        let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        return alert
    }
}
```

So in your viewcontroller you can for showing alert

```
let alert = Shared().waitAlert()
present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
   alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    //do your code
   })
})
```